# Can i change the Font style and size of "text" type email template?

Tags: soql, community, email, email-template

I have many "text" type email templates in classic salesforce version, but when i try to use those email templates and add few lines , i observe the font vary from template to the words i added. Hence felt can i make all email templates to common fonts and size.

Comment: Text templates, by definition, do not have any font formatting options. There would be a problem elsewhere, then. How are you composing these emails? What steps can we take to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for replying! Basically assuming you have few templates created. Now when you try to send an email from Case object and you have button to select the template of your choice. By selecting the template , body appears and i feel one of the details present should be edited. So when i edit, the font and size of the edited word looks different rest all. To avoid this i was thinking about ways such that i can make the templates with common style "new times roman" and size "11" which i use regularly, this wouldn't create any difference when i edit template while sending email